# How to remove selected radio button on a button click in Lightning datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

I am trying to deselect the radio button on click Next button, here is the sample code

JavaScript:

```
    <aura:attribute name="ArticleData" type="Object"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRows" type="List" default = "[]" />
    <lightning:datatable  keyField="id" data="{!v.ArticleData }" maxRowSelection="1"  onrowaction="{!c.handleRowAction }" onrowselection="{!c.getSelectedRows }"
                        selectedRows="{!v.selectedRows }" columns="{!v.columns }" aura:id="selrow" />
<div class="slds-clearfix">
    <div class="slds-page-header" role="banner">
        <div class="slds-float_right">            
              <lightning:button label="Prev" iconName="utility:chevronleft" iconPosition="left"
               onclick="{!c.handleAllPrev}" disabled="{! v.pageNumber == 1}"/>
               <lightning:button label="Next" iconName="utility:chevronright" iconPosition="right"
               disabled="{! v.isLastPage}" onclick="{!c.handleAllNext}"/>
        </div>
    <p>Page {!v.pageNumber} | Showing records from {! ((v.pageNumber-1)*v.pageSize)+' to '+((v.pageNumber-1)*v.pageSize+v.dataSize)}</p>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
handleAllNext : function(component, event) { 
        
        var selectedRows = event.getParam('selectedRows');
        console.log('SelectedRows.. '+JSON.stringify(selectedRows));
        //I have to set the selectedRows to null or undefined until I make my next selection, 
        //but unable to get the selected rows of lightning datatable attribute when I click on Next button
 
        var pageNumber = component.get("v.pageNumber");
        component.set("v.pageNumber", pageNumber+1);
        var a = component.get('c.displayAllQuestions');
        $A.enqueueAction(a);

    },
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try : `component.set("v.selectedRows", []);` ?

Comment: Hi Martin, yes, but that did not work